# Import styles css into a react js app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have a trouble importing .css stylesheet on a react basic app, I have this components:

AvatarHeader.js:

```
import styles from './AvatarHeader.css';

export default function AvatarHeader({ style, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img style={styles.image} src={Background} alt="background">
        { children }
      </img>
```

AvatarHeader.css:

```
.image {
   width: 400
}
```

AvatarHeader.js & AvatarHeader.css are in the same folder.

package.json:

```
  {
    "name": "UtWeb",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
      "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
      "react-scripts": "0.9.0",
      "webpack": "^2.2.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^15.4.2",
      "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
      "react-redux": "^4.3.0",
      "react-router": "^2.0.0",
      "redux": "^3.2.1",
      "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
  }
```

Styles aren't applied on the  component, but it's works if I rewrite AvatarHeader.js so:

```
  import styles from './AvatarHeader.css';

  const image = {
    width: 400
  }

  export default function AvatarHeader({ style, children }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <img style={image} src={Background} alt="background">
          { children }
        </img>
```

I don't understand how to fix this bug for use the first way to import css file.

Comment: You don't import the CSS file and use it like an object. You just have to import the file with no name just for side effects and then give the .image class to the img.

Comment: You may try to use [`css-object-loader`](https://github.com/pl12133/css-object-loader) instead of `css-loader`, since it will give you an object instead of loading the CSS globally (which is what `css-loader` does).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import './AvatarHeader.css';`
<img className='image' />`
```

is the correct syntax

Comment: Perfect! This works, but another question what pass if I have another imported css file with a 'image' class. How can i define where to use the class?

Comment: If you're using webpack and css-loader, you can define scope. More info here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#css-scope

Comment: this import css globally? or just for the component ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the CSS file name from `AvatarHeader.css` to `AvatoarHeader.module.css`.
then the import statement should be:
`import styles from './AvatarHeader.module.css'`. It should work now.
[see docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this problem again, the stylesheet needs to follow the [module naming convention](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) for the OP's original syntax to work.

So once the file is renamed `AvatarHeader.module.css`, the following React code should work:

```js
import styles from './AvatarHeader.module.css';

export default function AvatarHeader({ style, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img style={styles.image} src={Background} alt="background">
        { children }
      </img>
```